# what language it needs for developing applications on phonegap for android, iPhone and blackberry?

Tags: cordova, mobile

which languages should i know to develop application for android , iPhone, blackberry on phonegap sdk?

Answer (score 5):

As Anil has answered, you are going to need to know Javascript, Html and CSS (in that order or importance), however, with each platform you will also need to have some familiarity with each of the platforms native language (hopefully not very much, but still some). So to put it together it looks something like this.

**Base:**
Javascript, html5, CSS3. Focus first on the basics, but additionally, you will probably want to learn a particular framework for building interactive touch based web. Like JQuery or Sencha Touch.

**Additional:**
iOS -- Objective C
Android -- Java
Blackberry -- Java (I think, not a blackberry developer)

**Extra Additional:**
For applications that have even a moderate degree of complexity (like having user accounts, notifications, etc) you are going to want to learn some server side skills (for example, php or .net).

In the end, developing using Phonegap isn't necessarily any easier than developing a native app. But it does have some great cross platform features for rapid development. Just know that there is a learning curve here.

Hope this helps, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript, HTML5 and CSS3**....The developer should know these languages atleast.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to know HTML, HTML5 and CSS features but you will quickly see that knowledge of JavaScript is critical if you want to have a compelling application with advanced functionality.  This will also mean that you should learn 1-2 JavaScript mobile frameworks such as Sencha or jQuery Mobile.